# Regex to get values combined with "-" or "/" in Java

Tags: regex

I want to get some element in address string for example

`"Örnek Mah. Deneme Sk. No:24/8 Ankara"`

an address can be like this and i want to get 24/8 or it can combined with '-' also some combination of combined values

```
"b-10","b/150","1256-b"
```

digit part can be more than one but char part is only one letter.

thanx for your help...

Comment: try something like`\w+[/-]\w+`

Comment: did that work the way you expected it to work?

Comment: yes actually it did. i am trying  other combinations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this pattern

```
(\d+[/-]\d+)|(\w+[/-]\w+)
```

Comment: this find only first digit or letter after - , / i think answer of  @Onyambu worked fine . thank you for your interest

Comment: This pattern find first combination of digits followed by - or / then followed by digit or find any letter followed by - or / and followed by any letter again.

Comment: yes i realised that . but i want to get result of \w+[/-]\w+ pattern.